# How can I transform sql table from rows to column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I've table like this in mssql:

```
LogID | BatchID | Type
 240  | abc-def | Error
 241  | axc-d4f | Success
```

and so on.

I want to convert this table to like this :

If I can do this for all rows that will be great otherwise I am happy to filter a table with logid (select * from myTable m where m.LogId = 240)

```
RowId | LogID | ColName | ColValue
  1   |  240  | LogID   | 240
  2   |  240  | BatchID | abc-def
  3   |  240  | Type    | Error
```

I read about PIVOT, but couldn't figure out how can I use it in this scenario.
I am happy with any other kind of solution if it's possible.

Thanks,
Hakoo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use Apply..<kbd>[DEMO HERE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/752003)</kbd>

```
select 
row_number() over 
(partition by logid order by logid) as rownum,
logid,col1,col2 from #t t
    cross apply
    (
    values
    ('logid',cast(logid as varchar(30))),
    ('batchid',batchid),
    ('typee',typee)
    )b(col1,col2)
```

Comment: Glad it helped you,If you can include DDL,DML like the one in demo link and also any query you have attempted, you can get even faster responses